# Join two rows based on conditions

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>DescID</td>
    <td>From</td>
    <td>To</td>
    <td>Date</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Assigned</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Assigned</td>
    <td>Working</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Working</td>
    <td>Paused</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Paused</td>
    <td>Working</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Working</td>
    <td>Pending</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>Pending Reason</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Pending Client</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Pending</td>
    <td>Working</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>Pending Reason</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Pending Client</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Working</td>
    <td>Paused</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Paused</td>
    <td>Working</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Working</td>
    <td>Pending</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>Pending Reason</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Pending Client</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Pending</td>
    <td>Working</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>Pending Reason</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>Pending Client</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>Working</td>
    <td>Solved</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>Solved Type</td>
    <td>155</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Successfully</td>
    <td>2014-10-27</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is what I have on a mysql database and the information is generated by a support ticketing system.

As you can see the ticket status change is always identified by the DescID 20 and when the ticket goes to status Pending (waiting for information from the client) there is also inserted a Pending Reason identified by DescID 100. When the ticket is set to resolved (depending if it was successfully or not) there is also inserted a DescID 155 which is the resolved type.

Whenever the ticket bounces from AnyStatus to Pending a reason (DescID 180) is added and when the ticket comes back from Pending the DescID 180 is set back to blank.

I need to somehow (knowing that I can rely on the DescID) group the reasons with the status change in order to obtain something like

ID Description DescID From To Date Reason

Whenever the status does not require a reason the last one should be blank if there is a change to Pending the pending reason should be added to the Reason column.

I have tried to do this with a loop in python but I got stuck. I am able to detect the status change but I am not sure how to find the proper reason.

Pleas also note that the ID is not always consecutive but it will always be increasing.
This means that if status change to pending is ID 10, the next ID, even if it's id 100 it will be it's Pending Reason.

Hope this is somehow clear. If this could be done directly with an SQL query will be just AWESOME.
If not I would like to use python (loops,arrays) in order to solve my problem.

Thank you.

Later edit:

I have just made it in Excel and now I am wondering if it's possible to replicate it to pure SQL.
The excel formula is the following:

```html
<table border="1px">
<tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>B</td>
  <td>C</td>
  <td>D</td>
  <td>E</td>
  <td>F</td>
  <td>G</td>
  <td>H</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>15</td><td>9</td><td>Status</td><td>20</td><td>Working</td><td>Pending</td><td>2014-10-27</td><td></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td>16</td><td>14</td><td>Pending</td><td>Reason</td><td>100</td><td>Pending Client</td><td>2014-10-27</td><td></td></tr>
  </table>
```

The formula applied on G15 would be

if(F15="Pending",F16,"")

This will return the following row 15:

```html
<table border="1px">
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td></tr>
<tr><td>15</td><td>9</td><td>Status</td><td>20</td><td>Working</td><td>Pending</td><td>2014-10-27</td><td>Pending Client</td></tr></table>
```

So now I can totally ignore status 100 (which only provides the reason) as I have it next to it's afferent status 20.

Hope this make any sense, do you think it can be replicated in SQL ?

Comment: So you are showing `select * from mytable where ticketid = 123 and descid <> 180 order by id`here? And now you would like to select descid 180, too? But descid 180 gets reset, as you say. So in your example there would be no descid 180 record (or it would be empty), because the ticket is no longer pending!?

Comment: I need to move the Pending reason next to it's status change. So whenever there is a status change to Pending [DescID=20, To=Pending] I need to get the next DescID 100 (by ID, ascendent) and put it next to the status 22. What I want here is to actually calculate how much time was the ticket worked or pending (the date is in YYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss on the DB)

Comment: No, sorry, I still don't get it. Do you mean to say your IDs are not in proper order? That you want IDs sorted as ... -> 9 -> 17 -> 14 -> 15 -> ... So to have first to = 'Pending', then from = 'Pending Client', then to = 'Pending Client', then from = 'Pending'?

Comment: Hello, just edited my main question. Please check.

Comment: Please check: You want to select from your table and display an additional column REASON. That column will be empty except for records that go from something ('Working' usually) to 'Pending', for which you want to display the pending reason. From your original table you want to show these rows: 1, 2, 4, 7, 9 with reason from 14, 15, 18, 19, 20 with reason from 22, 23, 30, 35. Records 17 and 27 must be ignored. There is no DescID 180; that's a typo; you meant DescID 100. Reasons don't get set back to blank; although the ticket is no longer pending, the reasons in 14 and 22 still exist.